# how to clean the libs and headers files installed in yocto sysrootdir

Tags: yocto, openembedded, build-system

I have  compiled  the `yocto fido` and i want to clean required libs in `tmp/sysroot`dir instlled by some recipes like `qtbase-native`. can anyone guide me how to do that any particular commands are present or I need to delete manually ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Yocto does not provide any build in solution for cleaning files from shared headers area like tmp/sysroots/.

Indeed please familiar with this *do_clean* tasks (there exist 3 of them) which are available for every recipe: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-tasks-clean

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to delete tmp/.  It will be rebuild very quickly from sstate-cache.